# When i enable solr,the magento layered navigation not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalogsearch, search, solr

The issue is when i enabled solr (i successfully configured solr and tested successfully) in magento enterprise,the layered navigation filter is not working properly.

i.e displaying all category products not filter with attributes value.

If i set "No" in Enable Solr Engine for Catalog Navigation in admin panel it's working fine.

Path -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Enable Solr Engine for Catalog Navigation -> set to "No"

I analysed magento enterprise search module,but they not adding custom attributes into solr params.like attr_nav_select_"custom_attribute"

```
ex : http://localhost.com:8080/solr/test/select/?q=wine%0D%0A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=onq=test&qt=magento_en&fq=
%28visibility:3+OR+visibility:4%29+AND+store_id:13+AND+in_stock:true
```

Any one tell me is this magento issue or i need to configure any other matter.

Anything i would appreciate.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.i update in catalog.xml under `<catalog_category_layered>`

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

changed to

```
    <reference name="left">
<block type="enterprise_search/catalog_layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

now i am getting attribute values in solr params like "attr_nav_select_brand:13"

```
http://localhost.com:8080/solr/test/select/?q=test&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+(attr_nav_select_brand:13)+AND+store_id:3+AND+in_stock:true
```

but i don't know how to pass multiple values for specific attribute.any one guide me or suggest me how to make URL for multiple values for attribute.in default magento working with single value for attribute.

the category url like

```
http://localhost.com/whiskies.html?brand=Dreamer&mode=list&pack_size_in_litres=2+litres
```

Comment: Please close the issue as well. Leaving answered issues open is bad for the site as whole.

Comment: This is timely for me as I'm working on the same issue. Any luck here?

Comment: Hi philwinkle, it working with single value for attributes like "attr_nav_select_brand:13" if you want multi values for attributes please use any third party plugin.like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html